# Docz: How to render Typescript definitions other than interfaces as props

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

We are in the process of documenting our type definitions with Docz. It has been working well for interfaces, however providing anything other than interfaces to the Docz components as props doesn't seem to render anything.

I was wanting to know how to render an enum or union type and have it be able to rendered in the mdx.

The way they are consumed on the docz file is like so:

interface.tsx:

```
import {
  UserOrganisation,
  UserLevel
} from "~/packages/database-interfaces/src";

export const UserLevelC = (props: UserLevel) => {};
export const UserOrganisationC = (props: UserOrganisation) => {};
```

index.mdx:

```
---
name: users
menu: Database/Realtime
---

import { Props } from "docz";
import {
  UserLevelC,
  UserOrganisationC
} from "./Interface.tsx";


# Interface

## Properties

### Type UserOrganisation

<Props of={UserOrganisationC} />

### Type UserLevel

<Props of={UserLevelC} />
```

With types defined like this:

```
export const enum UserLevel {
  "employee",
  "owner",
  "admin",
  "disabled"
}

export interface UserOrganisation {
  level: UserLevel;
  name: string;
}
```

This renders like so (note the 'UserLevel' type below which just renders as a horizontal line):

[image]

For reference we have also tried defining / exporting these ways:

```
export type foo = 'option1' | 'option2';
export enum foo = 'option1' | 'option2';
export const enum foo = 'option1' | 'option2';
```

As you can see, the interfaces are rendered but not this type / enum etc.

What's weird is if the same sort of enumerated string / union type is declared as the property of an interface rather than its own type:

```
export interface UserOrganisation {
  level: 'employee' | 'owner' | 'admin' | 'disabled';
  name: string;
}
```

Docz can display it when rendering the interface like so:

[image]

However when you try and extract it into its own type (which we need to as this and some others are used in multiple places by other interfaces), is when nothing renders.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since `level: 'employee' | 'owner' | 'admin' | 'disabled';` works you can declare the type as that:

```
type UserLevel = 'employee' | 'owner' | 'admin' | 'disabled';
```

Comment: Hi basarat,
Thanks yes we have tried that, as noted here: 

 `export type foo = 'option1' | 'option2';
export enum foo = 'option1' | 'option2';
export const enum foo = foo = 'option1' | 'option2';`

 However it doesnt render anything on the docz end when passed as props. Only interfaces and enumerated properties within interfaces seem to. This seems to make it only suitable for objects, as as soon as you extract the type out of an interface it no longer renders.